# Using a gerund after "to be" - "I promise to be writing"

Tags: grammaticality, gerunds

Recently I have seen gerund after "to be" for example:

> I promise to be writing a new novel.

I beg someone's help to explain this sentence and its grammar to me.

Comment: It seems a little strange. Perhaps the writer meant "I promise to **start** writing a new novel."?

Comment: That's technically not a gerund but a participle.  A gerund is a verb form used like a noun ("I like *skiing*"); a participle is used like an adjective ("I am *skiing*).  You can certainly say "I promise to write", so you can also put another verb there: "I promise to *be*..."  And what do you promise to be?  Writing.  You could explain it as "I promise to *be performing the action of writing*."

Comment: Did this sentence have any context? It sounds like it's missing something, for example, "I promise to be writing a new novel [as soon as I'm finished with this one]" as in "I promise to be [in the state of doing something when my current state has ended]." What do you think? Do you think this is looking too deeply into this?

Answer (score 1):

**To be writing** is the progressive infinitive (**writing** is a participle). Like other progressive forms progressive infinitives suggest that actions are,were or will be continuing around the time that we are speaking about.There should be some context, some explanation.

> I am going to think it over today.This time tomorrow I promise to be writing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a common use of the stative verb "promise" along with the (uncommon) infinitive of the simple present progressive.

> I am writing
>
> I promise to write
>
> I promise to be writing.

It means that, at some point in the future, I intend to be doing some activity.  The use of the present progressive emphasizes the *action* itself, the physical activity of putting words on paper (or in a computer, etc.), as compared with the general concept of "writing".  Otherwise you would just use the simple present:

> I promise to write.

You can use this same form with other stative verbs like "prefer":

> I prefer to be sleeping when the sun rises.

Again, I want to emphasize that, at a moment in time, I am *doing* something (while something else is happening).  Otherwise just use the simple present:

> I prefer to sleep past sunrise.